# Visual Studio 2013 Register Office 365 Service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, office365, azure-active-directory, adal

I have a problem when trying to add some `Office 365 Apis` in my `ASP.NET` project.
My `VS 2013` is up to date, with the latest Tools for `Office SDK` installed.
My office 365 tenant is correct and by the way attached correctly with my Azure account.

During the Register your app process I have an error reported :

> Unsupported token. Unable to initialize the authorization context.

Here is the image :

[image]

I try in `VS 2015` too, the exception is the same.

Within Fiddler, here is the exception raised after a `GET` Request :

```
https://graph.windows.net/f8cdef31-...-5f571e91255a/servicePrincipals()?$filter='3c7fc52e-...-'%20eq%20appId&api-version=1.5
```

The `JSON` response is :

```
{"odata.error":
{"code":"Request_BadRequest",
"message":{"lang":"en","value":"Unsupported token. Unable to initialize the authorization context."}
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Sebastien, sorry that you are hitting this issue. I have a couple of questions.  Do you see a login prompt (to sign in to your tenant/directory)?  Have you tried making sure that you don't have any other browsers open where you are already logged in?  Have you tried clearing your cookie cache?

Comment: Hi Dan, Thx for taking time for troobleshooting this problem.
Finally I managed to make it work, using the Office 365 admin account instead of using the Azure AD admin account.
This a strange behavior in my opinion, but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to make it work, using the Office 365 admin account instead of using the Azure AD admin account. This a strange behavior in my opinion, but it works :)